# ReferenceError: item is not defined in Azure insert script

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-table-storage

I am using the following code in insert to perform push notifications. TodoItem Table contains imageurl and Channel Table has channl uris. The reference for this code is here-http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-push-vs2012/

The following is the code for insert script in TodoItem Table

```
var azure = require('azure');

var qs = require('querystring');

var appSettings = require('mobileservice-config').appSettings;



function insert(item, user, request) {

    // Get storage account settings from app settings.

    var accountName = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;

    var accountKey = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY;

    var host = accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';



    if ((typeof item.containerName !== "undefined") && (

        item.containerName !== null)) {

        // Set the BLOB store container name on the item, which must be lowercase.

        item.containerName = item.containerName.toLowerCase();



        // If it does not already exist, create the container

        // with public read access for blobs.       

        var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey, host);

        blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(item.containerName, {

            publicAccessLevel: 'blob'

        }, function(error) {

                if (!error) {



                    // Provide write access to the container for the next 5 mins.       

                    var sharedAccessPolicy = {

                        AccessPolicy: {

                            Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,

                            Expiry: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000)

                        }

                    };



                    // Generate the upload URL with SAS for the new image.

                    var sasQueryUrl =

                        blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(item.containerName,

                            item.resourceName, sharedAccessPolicy);



                    // Set the query string.

                    item.sasQueryString = qs.stringify(sasQueryUrl.queryString);



                    // Set the full path on the new new item,

                    // which is used for data binding on the client.

                    item.imageUri = sasQueryUrl.baseUrl + sasQueryUrl.path;



                } else {

                    console.error(error);

                }

                request.execute({
        success: function() {
            request.respond();
            sendNotifications();
        }
    });

            });

    } else {

        request.execute({
        success: function() {
            request.respond();
            sendNotifications();
        }
    });




}
}
function sendNotifications() {
        var registrationsTable = tables.getTable('Channel');
        registrationsTable.read({
            success: function(registrations) {
                registrations.forEach(function(registration) {
                    push.wns.sendToastText04(registration.handle, {
                        text1: item.text
                    }, {
                        success: function(pushResponse) {
                            console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The error is Error in callback for table 'Channel'. ReferenceError: item is not defined
    at :122:32
    [external code]
    at Object.registrationsTable.read.success (:120:31)
    [external code]

Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this block of code: success: function(registrations) { }.

I would remove the call to push.wns and log to console to try to debug.  Check that 'item' exists.  If you're using the online node editor it will show you if you have any unmatched brackets.

I'm assuming you have configured WNS for use in the Azure portal?

Comment: ,Yeah the error is in that code block as you had pointed out but i am unable to find out where the mistake lies. Any advice or suggestions?

Comment: It says 'external code' so I would suggest you check the configuration of your WNS setup in the Azure portal.  If you can remove the push call and replace with a console.log and see if it executes fine then you'll be able to pinpoint the problem code.